# Linking values of one column to two different columns in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

There are 3 columns I'm working with in a .csv file:
HomeTeam AwayTeam FTR (Full Time Result)

[image: EPL matches]

I want to add a column "Winner" and have it display the names of the team that won instead of H or A in FTR, and maybe have D display as 'Draw'.

So what I expect to see as a result is:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp5nJ.png)

I'm Still learning so I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following lambda expression:

```
df['Winner'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['HomeTeam'] if x['FTR'] == 'H' else (x['AwayTeam'] if x['FTR'] == 'A' else 'Draw'), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to solve this using `np.select`:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'HomeTeam': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'AwayTeam': ['D', 'E', 'F'],
    'FTR': ['H', 'A', 'D'],
})

df['Winner'] = np.select([df['FTR'] == 'H', df['FTR'] == 'A'], [df['HomeTeam'], df['AwayTeam']], default='Draw')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  HomeTeam AwayTeam FTR Winner
0        A        D   H      A
1        B        E   A      E
2        C        F   D   Draw
```